# .setBackgroundResource(0) crashing my app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In app, I allocate resources to button in GridLayout.

```
if(fill[tappedButtonLocation] == 2 && !gameOver) {
            fill[tappedButtonLocation] = activePlayer;
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                tappedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_yellow);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                tappedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_yelp);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
        }
```

Then I want to remove the resources but it crash the app.

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
        ((Button) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
```

Allocated resource is

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFC00"> </solid>
    <size android:height="120dp"
        android:width="120dp"> </size>
</shape>
```

Logcat Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
        at com.example.tictokgame.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:65)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

How can I remove the resource from GridView.
[Actually I want to reset the tic-toc-toe game after clicking on play again button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAXdC.png)

Comment: what's the crash? is there a stack trace?

Comment: Question is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be a `ClassCastException` as noted in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
```

Please check your imports in the class, where you do the following:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

Change this:

```
import android.widget.GridLayout;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
```

Comment: Thant's  work but it's remove default background to. I want to restore the default background color of button.

Comment: Im not quite sure but you can try this: `setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default)`